# Shrubs identification

Tags: identification, shrubs, landscaping

This is the picture ([large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OMFN.jpg)) we took the first summer we moved here.

[image: Plant 1]

My wife trimmed and cut quite a bit in this area and this year it looks like this ([large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HuIe.jpg)).

[image: Plant 2]

What are these shrubs? Can the two pictures actually be the same thing? I suspect my wife may have killed another plant, but based on the spacing between the shrubs this year, if the first picture were another plant, it would be a really large weed plant.

**[UPDATE]** Added a close-up.

[image: Flower] ([large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTgDQ.jpg))

Comment: Can you add a close-up photo of a leaf or two? I can't get a good look at the leaves even in the large photos.

Comment: They certainly could be the same plant, in fact they look quite similar, with the only difference being color. Lots of things can affect the color of plant leaves.

Comment: Higher resolution photos would be very helpful - magnifying your existing photos doesn't make them any clearer, so the leaves cannot be seen clearly.

Comment: Just took a close-up picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shrubs are spirea, and assuming that the first picture was taken in late summer and the second one this spring, then they're probably the cultivar Gold Mound. Of course, they could also be one of the other dozen or two spirea cultivars common in the nursery trade. Their flowers should be rosy or dusky-rose clusters.

Comment: Yes, Gold Mound Spirea looks very similar!! I didn't recall them flowering last Summer but maybe we missed it.